# Microsoft.SyncFileSyncProvider for REST Backend?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to build my own Sync Desktop application like onedrive to sync with a REST backend. MS Sync FW seemed to be a good base for that. Now my approach would be to use the FileSyncProvider to cover the local files and write another Provider - closely based on the FileSyncProvider for the REST backend. **Is this a viable approach?**

The deeper I get into the Sync Framework the more I think that I might to write two custom providers - my own LocalFileSyncProvider and a RemoteFileSyncProvider. **Are there any good examples for something like that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you might need to implement only one simple custom provider, the one that interacts with the REST service. Then you can synchronize between the out of the box FileSyncProvider and your simple custom provider.

If you want more information on the type of custom providers, check the following link:

[Choosing a Custom Provider type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902844(v=sql.110).aspx)

The code sample that you are looking for is here:

[File Sync with Simple Custom Provider Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/File-Sync-with-Simple-c497bf87)